# How to check if a given windows user may logon as a service

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have to program a custom action for a Windows installer (WiX 3) to check the windows account to use for the windows service that will be installed.

To use the LocalSystem account for the service is not an option here, because the service has to work with windows file shares, given by their UNC paths.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult VerifyServiceUser(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            session.Log("VerifyServiceUser: Begin");

            PrincipalContext context = null;
            if (session["SERVICE_USERNAME"].Contains("\\"))
            {
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            }
            else
            {
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
            }
            using (context)
            {
                if (context.ValidateCredentials(session["SERVICE_USERNAME"], session["SERVICE_PASSWORD"]))
                {
                    // TODO: Check the user is allowed to login as a service.

                    session["SERVICE_USER_VALID"] = "1";
                }
            }

            session.Log("VerifyServiceUser: End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("VerifySqlConnection: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I can't find any information about how to check with c# if the user is allowed to login as a service. That is absolutely necessary here.

Hopefully you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Does NETWORK_SERVICE have the required permissions?

Comment: @Neil No, unfortunately not. LocalSystem and NETWORK_SERVICE can only access Windows file shares, if anonymous access would be allowed. Of course that's not an option for security reasons.

Comment: Can you create an account specifically for your application, with the correct permissions (kinda like Android does for each application).

Comment: @Neil Technically I could do that, but to use an already existing user to access the file shares is a hard requirement by our customers. so that is sadly also not an option.